# On OSX, rosmake -a could not find roslib

Tags: macos-mountain-lion, ros-fuerte, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS Fuerte on OSX 10.8.2 Mountain Lion.
I followed the step-by-step instructions on:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source
It was all successful (with a few modifications though) until I get to run:

> sudo rosmake -a

Python reports roslib (1.8.9) not found.
Anyone can help me trouble shooting that?

> dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rosmake", line 4, in 
> import pkg_resources
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in 
> working_set.require(**requires**)
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
> needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
> raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: roslib==1.8.9

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45349/on-osx,-rosmake--a-could-not-find-roslib/) by [Qianyi Zhou](https://answers.ros.org/users/3345/qianyi-zhou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/43032/issues-about-installing-ros-on-mountain-lion/)?

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1